# SPF records and spoofing

Tags: email, spam, spoofing, spf

Lets say we have this SPF record

```
v=spf1 include:spf.protection.outlook.com include:spf.onprem.com -all`
```

And this record

```
v=spf1 include:spf.protection.outlook.com include:spf.onprem.com ?all
```

What would be the difference ?
Would record1 actually be valid and record2 will be useless in regard of spoofing ? The ?all should mean "Neutral" so it would be like spf is disabled.

Answer (score 3):

What is happening here depends on the mail server (MTA) applying the policy. In case the address matches the result will be the same: Pass.

In case of non-match the result will be different though: either Fail or Neutral. Some MTA might block the mail on Fail, although this is usually considered a bad idea due to the chance of false positives. Most spam analysis will at least treat Fail and Neutral differently by applying a different spam score or similar.

If a DMARC policy exists and is checked by the MTA then the DMARC result will be the same for both SPF policies though, since the only relevant part is if the SPF policy resulted in a clear Pass or in something else.

Comment: Well, in the server I am talking about, spoofed emails get delivered without being flagged at spam. When I tried sending emails from an SMTP server (external), I could impersonate any user email in my organisation.

Comment: @user269161: which matches what I said regarding spam score applied to the mail.